# How do I change a single value in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, cell

How can one change a single cell in a `data.frame` to something else?

Basically I just want to rename that one cell, not all cells which matches it.

I can´t use the `edit()` command because it will screw up my script since I'm using the `data.frame` on several occasions.

Answer (score 58):

```
data.frame[row_number, column_number] = new_value
```

For example, if `x` is your data.frame:

```
x[1, 4] = 5
```

Comment: Is it possibe to edit cell value by column name and row name?

Comment: @runjumpfly data_frame["row_name", "col_name"]=2

Answer (score 40):

Suppose your dataframe is df and you want to change gender from 2 to 1 in participant id 5 then you should determine the row by writing "==" as you can see

```
 df["rowName", "columnName"] <- value
 df[df$serial.id==5, "gender"] <- 1
```

Comment: Most useful answer of the lot.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

To change a cell value using a column name, one can use

```
iris$Sepal.Length[3]=999
```

Answer (score 8):

In RStudio you can write directly in a cell.
Suppose your data.frame is called `myDataFrame` and the row and column are called `columnName` and `rowName`.
Then the code would look like:

```
myDataFrame["rowName", "columnName"] <- value
```

Hope that helps!