# Why can't I edit values in this data frame?

Tags: r

I have a mid-sized data frame with two busted rows. The addresses are bad, so `geocode()` didn't geocode them and so I don't have lat/long info for either.

I tried making a temp frame to play with:

```
tmp.frame <- subset(all.sites, is.na(all.sites$lat))
```

I can update values in `tmp.frame` with `tmp.frame$Address <- c("Better Address 1","Better Addresss 2")` but I can't seem to edit the value in the larger frame. `all.sites[392, 7]` is one of the spots with missing lat/lon and I [thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782206/how-do-i-change-a-single-value-in-a-data-frame) that `all.sites[392, 7] = c("Better Addy")` would do the trick, but instead I'm getting this:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "Better Addy") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Curiously, `tmp.frame[2,4] = c("Better")` works just fine. So I'm not sure what the difference between the two is.

Note: when I try `vi(all.sites[392,7])` I get this, roughly:

```
structure(NA_integer_, .Label = c("10003 39th Avenue",..., class = "factor")
```

Comment: I believe the problem may be that some of your columns are being converted to factors, rather than numeric or characters. This may be relevant if that's the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to put a character class value into what is likely a factor class column. Perhaps `tmp.frame$Address <- as.factor(c("Better Address 1","Better Addresss 2"))` would work

Comment: @Csislander Sounds about right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That happens because the column you are trying to update is a `factor`, which by definition has a limited domain (set of possible values). When you try to force an entry to be a level that was not part of this domain, this produces a warning and an `NA`. Try this:

```
ff <- factor(sample(1:3, size=20, replace=TRUE))  ## factor of 1, 2, and 3
ff[5] <- 4    ## try changing the fifth entry to an 'unknown' value
levels(ff)    ## show set of known values
```

If you want to be able to modify the values to anything you like, you need to convert the factor to a `character`, or `integer` (depending on what it represents). Only change to a factor after you are confident all possible values are there. You can also specify them manually:

```
ff2 <- factor(sample(1:3, size=20, replace=TRUE), levels=1:4)  ## 1-4 are legal
ff2[5] <- 4    ## accepted without problems
head(ff2)      ## check
```