# Sub-setting csv structure based upon the value in last row

Tags: r

I have read a `.csv` file which has 785 rows and 24217 columns.

```
my_data <- read.csv("test.csv", header = FALSE)
```

I want to segregate the columns where the value in `785` row is `6`. So I tried the following:

```
my_data[my_data[1:24217][785,] == 6]
```

the result of which is mixed up columns, like in a list. How could I get the resulting structure which would still resemble the structure in `csv/my_data`. All I want is to subset `my_data` where the value in 785th row for each column is 6.

Sample set:

```
      V1       V2       V3       V4    .   .   .     .    . N th Column
1   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
2   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
3   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
4   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
5   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
6   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
7   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
8   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
9   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
10  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
.
.
.
785  0.000000 6.000000 5.50000
```

As you could see in the above set that are 785 rows and N columns which in my case go upto 24217. I want to subset data based upon the value in 785th row. So, I want to separate columns where last value is 6 (in the 785 row).

Comment: This may have been answered already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782206/how-do-i-change-a-single-value-in-a-data-frame

Comment: Have you actually read the question?  I do not believe OP is trying to change a value of anything,...rather, this seems to be a subsetting question.

Comment: @W.Dodge I am sorry, but I do not think this is a duplicate.

Comment: maybe it would be helpful if you provided a small sample df and a desired result...

Comment: @pyll Updated..

Comment: ok, so in your updated example...your desired output is all 785 rows, but only one column ('V2')...assuming all the other columns do not have a 6 in the 785th row.  correct?

Comment: @pyll Yeah. I want all columns where the value in 785th row is `6`. There would be many columns where value in 785th row would be `6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Sample data looks like this.
# Multiple columns V1-VN (only 4 here for example)

V1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
V2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6)
V3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.5)
V4 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6)
df <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3, V4)

# You wants to subset the data by
# keeping the columns which have specific value (6)
# in a certain row (Row 7 here for simplicity)

newdf <- df[,df[7,]==6]

# So try this for your problem
newmy_data <- my_data[,my_data[785,]==6]
```

Update: Request for multiple conditions led to this answer

```
newdf <- df[,df[7,] %in% c(6, 5.5)]
```

Comment: Updated the sample set in question

Comment: I think, that is fine. Could you please explain what exactly have you done and how is it different from what I have tried (as given in the question)?

Comment: Sure.  The first thing is actually assigning the new subset to a df, which is what `newdf <-` is doing.  Then, it's just a matter of getting the logic right.  I am starting with `df`, then I want all rows, but only the columns where my condition is true.

Comment: Why is it necessary to wrap `my_data[785,]==6` in `c`?

Comment: Actually...it looks like it's not.  I was thinking it had to return a list of columns.  but was wrong.  Updated answer.

Comment: Okay. I had approached it like `my_data[my_data[1:24217][785,] == 6]`. Is it an incorrect way?

Comment: it's not necessary to specify the columns like that.  In fact, that seems to be concatenating the columns into a long list.  the answer i gave provides the desired format

Comment: If I need to also get rows with value 5.  Will the following be okay? `my_data[,my_data[785,]==6 || my_data[785,]==5]`?

Comment: No.  Try this.  `newmy_data <- my_data[,my_data[785,] %in% c(6, 5)]`