# R: change single value of data.frame returns invalid factor level warning

Tags: r, dataframe, warnings, cell

My question is a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782206/how-do-i-change-a-single-value-in-a-data-frame) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819956/warning-message-in-invalid-factor-level-na-generated) question.

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3,4),
                 "char" = c("a","b","c","d"))
```

and I want to change a single value, like

```
df[1,1] <- 10
```

which is working. When I try this

```
df[2,2] <- "f"
```

or

```
df$char[1] <- "f"
```

or

```
df$char[1] <- as.character("f")
```

I get the following warning:

```
"Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 2, value = c(1L, NA, 3L, 4L)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated"
```

How do I change the content in the column "char"?

Comment: easiest approach would be to do `df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
                 char = c("a","b","c","d"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and then everything would work.

Comment: @RonakShah that works if they have access to creating the data frame like this, but that could easily not be their real life situation

Comment: @camille You are right. I'm looking for a simple solution for data frames, which are already created..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can include `levels` beforehand and then do the assignment

```
df$char <- factor(df$char, levels = c(levels(df$char), "f"))
df[2,2] <- "f"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. But I'm still wondering, why this allegedly simple assignment requires two lines of rather tricky code..

Comment: @DerDressing  Because `factor` columns need that level before the assignment