# R - select element from each row by index

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

Suppose I have a matrix, for instance `m = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), ncol = 3)` and a vector `v = c(3, 2)`. `v` is the index of element from each row to take, so the result would be `c(5, 4)`. How to achieve this, keeping operations vectorized?

Comment: The third element in the first row is 5 and the second element in the second row is 4. How is (6,5) the desired result? What am I missing here?

Comment: Please see the last answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782206/how-do-i-change-a-single-value-in-a-data-frame/57463973#57463973).

Comment: @MohamedRahouma Did you link to the wrong answer? What you posted doesn't seem at all related to the question. There's no replacement happening here.

Comment: @MrFlick you're right, I corrected example. Anyway, question solved.